# delete row from ACF repeater field

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I have a button that when you click it, it triggers an ajax call to a function that should delete a row in a acf repeater field based on a data attribute.

Here's the function, but row in question doesn't delete:

```
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_remove_from_playlist','remove_from_playlist');
add_action( 'wp_ajax_remove_from_playlist', 'remove_from_playlist' );

function remove_from_playlist() {
    $field_key = 'field_5b6b8c16eb66b';
    $userID = $_POST['user'];
    $lessonID = $_POST['lessonID'];

    if( have_rows('user_playlist', $userID) ):
        while( have_rows('user_playlist', $userID) ) : the_row();
            $value = get_sub_field('post_id');

            if($value === $lessonID) {
                $row = get_row_index();
                delete_row($field_key, $row, $userID);
            }
        endwhile;
    endif;
    die();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is not very well documented; you need to tell ACF that you are passing a user ID, not a post ID. To do this, append `user_` to your variable:

```
if( have_rows('user_playlist', 'user_' . $userID) ):
    while( have_rows('user_playlist', 'user_' . $userID) ) : the_row();
        $value = get_sub_field('post_id');

        if($value === $lessonID) {
            $row = get_row_index();
            delete_row($field_key, $row, 'user_' . $userID);
        }
    endwhile;
endif;
```

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more clear... so the $userID variable already has the user_ in it. So the actual $userID value is user_1, since I'm signed in as the admin.

Comment: Above code works, so there must be something about your Ajax call or the POST parameters that is causing the isse.

Comment: If someone need to remove all rows of a repeater use `while (delete_row('field', 1)` instead, as `delete_row` change the index (so it is not reliable to use inside a loop).