# Delete ACF user profile repeater field row from user account (WordPress)

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I am using ACF repeater field for user profiles, which shows like this in the user profile page:

[image]

That's cool.

But on the front-end I have a form that I want to use to delete a specific row. My custom form simply lists all the rows with radio buttons, and so if the user selected number 3 and submitted the form then I want to delete the third row (in this example, the row with Catherine Davies would be deleted).

The form works fine in that it submits as expected and returns the value the user selected, but my code to delete the row that was selected doesn't seem to work.

The [ACF documentation seems a little vague](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/delete_sub_row/) on the subject. Based on a combination of the ACF doc and [this StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52805619/delete-row-from-acf-repeater-field), I expect this code to work but it does not:

```
$user_ID        = get_current_user_id();
$field          = 'extra_user_info'; // Name of the repeater field
$row_to_delete  = $_POST["row_to_delete"];

delete_sub_row($field, $row_to_delete, 'user_' . $user_id);
```

Just to be sure, even if I hardcode the `$row_to_delete` variable to any number (from 1 to 4) it still does not delete any row.

Just to clarify, I wish to delete an entire row.

**Note:** I realise I could just embed the ACF form on the front-end, but for reasons I won't go into this is not an option, hence using my own custom form.

Comment: You are not inside the loop here, so I think you should be using this syntax: https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/delete_sub_row/#delete-a-sub-row-outside-of-a-haverows-loop

Comment: I'd seen that before, but can't see how that let's me delete a specific row number for a specific user ID.

Comment: If you want to remove the whole row, then didn't you pick the wrong function to begin with? I think that should be done using https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/delete_row/

Comment: I need to delete a sub row, not a row (remember I'm using a repeater field). There are two different functions for those purposes. Hence `delete_sub_row()` is probably the correct one to use. Sorry if that wasn't clear.

Comment: _"delete_row - Deletes a row of data from an existing Repeater or Flexible Content field value."_ - I think that _is_ what you want, no? The `John, Smith, 123456789`, that is data from one _row_ of your repeater, is it not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There could be another issue but in your example at least, your `$user_ID` variable has capital letters, while the variable passed to `delete_sub_row()` is lowercase. PHP variables are [case-sensitive](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.basics.php#:%7E:text=Variables%20in%20PHP%20are%20represented,variable%20name%20is%20case%2Dsensitive.).

Comment: now that's a little embarrassing. delete_row() was the required function after all (although still confusing that there is also a delete_sub_row() function when delete_row() can be used to delete a row or sub row), and also that I didn't even notice the case sensitivity issue in the variable name. So the final code is: `delete_row($field, $row_to_delete, 'user_' . $user_ID);`. Good spotting.

Comment: Lol no worries, glad you got it working!